# JBossWS 3.3.1 upgrade client returns HTTP 404 Not Found exception

Tags: web-services, websphere, jbossws

Web service - Service is on WAS v7. Client is on JBoss v5. We recently upgraded to JBossWS 3.3.1. Since then the client is unable to communicate with the service on WAS.

Without any changes to code, we get the below exception

```
2012-01-19 14:42:15,317 ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS]->error@419 (ajp-cwsappdev01%2F205.132.14.29-8109-1) 
SOAP request exception java.io.IOException: 
Error initializing socket factory SSL context: Can not find truststore url.
```

Added the following lines of code to the client:

```
((BindingProvider) impl).getRequestContext().put(StubExt.PROPERTY_KEY_STORE, "/usr/local/jee/.../cacerts"));
((BindingProvider) impl).getRequestContext().put(StubExt.PROPERTY_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD, "*****"));
((BindingProvider) impl).getRequestContext().put(StubExt.PROPERTY_CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, "0");
```

After making the code change, am getting the below error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: Invalid HTTP server response [404] - Not Found
```

Any ideas? I added the chunked encoding property, as WAS does not support it properly. Any other incompatibility between JBoss and WebSphere App Server?

Thanks for your help in advance!

==================
I made some code changes and am now getting the below message. I use JBossWS-Native 3.3.1 and JAX-WS 2.1 versions. Does any one know how I can disable chunked encoding in JBoss?
File standard-jaxws-client-config.xml moved into one of JBoss the core JARS - updating it would need me to 'unjar' - edit file - and jar back again.

```
2012-01-24 10:35:57,930 WARN  [org.jboss.ws.core.client.transport.NettyClient]->warn@352 (ajp-cwsappdev01%2F205.132.14.29-8109-4) Can't set chunk size from call properties, illegal value provided!
2012-01-24 10:35:58,001 ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient]->error@419 (ajp-cwsappdev01%2F205.132.14.29-8109-4) Exception caught while (preparing for) performing the invocation: 
java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message
at org.jboss.ws.core.client.transport.NettyClient.invokeInternal(NettyClient.java:229)
at org.jboss.ws.core.client.transport.NettyClient.invoke(NettyClient.java:121)
at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:150)
at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.invoke(SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.java:69)
at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:369)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:302)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:181)
at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:161)
at $Proxy796.getCWSAccount(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I am using JBossWS-Native 3.3.1 and JAX-WS 2.1 version. I tried several ways to set chunk size to 0 - and always get the below warning message:

Answer (score 0):

Cause: Although the client had port specified as 8004 in the endpoint URL; when the request hit the service it was coming in for port 443. We moved/"attached" the service to port 443 and the web server was able to map it to the right application. will need to figure out why/where the endpoint was changed fro 8004 to 443..